# Location of jQuery script in HTML5 Boilerplate file?

Tags: html5boilerplate

Does H5BP assume that you will write your JavaScript and jQuery code so that it only executes when the window has fully loaded (using the onload listener)?  The reason I ask is that H5BP locates the jQuery inclusion script tag at the bottom of the body tag as shown below.  However, the script in which a cookie is being set will not work unless I move the jquery.min.js script element to the head element which precedes the body (and thus the execution of the cookie script).  Thanks.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
        <title></title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
        <script src="js/vendor/modernizr-2.6.2.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>This is HTML5 Boilerplate.</p>

        <!-- Cookie isn't set when jquery.min.js follows this element block  -->
        <script>
            var test_profile = { browserWidth: $(window).width() };
            document.cookie = "test_profile=" + JSON.stringify(test_profile);
        </script>

        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/vendor/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That first `<script>` block depends on jQuery (`$(window).width()`), so it cannot be used before jQuery has been loaded.

Just move that cookie script after the other two `<script>` blocks:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/vendor/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"><\/script>')</script>

<script>
    var test_profile = { browserWidth: $(window).width() };
    document.cookie = "test_profile=" + JSON.stringify(test_profile);
</script>
```